# Map range to single value Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mapping

I'm looking for any better way to implement the following in Javascript or in JSON format.

```
function getGroupId(val) {
    let groupId = 0;
    if (val < 5) {
        groupId = 0;
    } else if (val < 10) {
        groupId = 1;
    } else if (val < 25) {
        groupId = 2;
    } else if (val < 36) {
        groupId = 3;
....

    } else {
        groupId = 8;
    }
    return groupId;
}
```

Comment: If your code is working fine and you just looking for better implementation you just ask this on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can't even imagine how JSON would be related to this

Comment: @GuyIncognito I guess that means object literal.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this

```js
const mapping = [5,10,25,36]

function getGroupId(val) {
  let groupId = 8;
  for (let i=0; i<mapping.length;i++) { // using simple for to be able to break
    if (val<mapping[i]) { groupId = i; break }
  }  
  return groupId;
}

console.log(getGroupId(1),getGroupId(11),getGroupId(50))
```